# Set num of output shard in Write.to(Sink) in dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am having a customized sink extending `FileBasedSink` to which I write to by calling `PCollection.apply(Write.to(MySink))` in dataflow (very simpler to [XmlSink.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/XmlSink.java)). However it seems by default simply calling `Write.to` will always result to 3 output shards? Is there any way that I could define the number of output shard (like `TextTO.Write.withNumShards`) just in customized sink class definition? or I have to define another customized `PTransformer` like `TextIO.Write`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, right now `FileBasedSink` does not support specifying the number of shards.

In practice, the number of shards you get will be dependent on how the framework chooses to optimize the parts of the pipeline producing the collection you're writing, so there's essentially no control over that.

I've filed [a JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-159) for your request so you can subscribe to the status.

Comment: thanks jkff, ahh want to make clear to myself, is all customized sink not able to support control over number of output shard? and so in your opinion what is the best route to go at current point to enable flexible number of output shard with my customized sink?

Comment: I think the only way to achieve this currently is without the custom sink API: pipe your data through a ParDo {hash the data modulo numShards} | GBK | ParDo {write data of this shard to a temporary file; in finishBundle, atomically rename it to the final location}.

Comment: But note that this will also not work in many services because of dynamic work rebalancing

Comment: Sorry, I should have made myself more clear - the final ParDo should be ParDo {(shardIdx, values) => write "values" to a temporary file and at the end atomically rename it to final location}. Dynamic rebalancing won't split the values of a key, so this will work.